# How can I keep an HTML snippet in a separate file, plug variables in as needed, and echo it out on demand?

Tags: php, code-snippets

For instance, let's say I have a snippet of code, which I'd like to keep separate. for now, we'll call it `snippet.php`.

`snippet.php` would be a simple block of reusable HTML which would have php variables in it. Something like this:

```
<article>
    <h1>{$headline}</h1>
    <p>${$body}</p>
</article>
```

I'd like to be able to return this code from a function, along the lines of this:

```
function writeArticle($headline, $body){
    return "contents of snippet.php using the variables passed in to the function"
}
```

I know I could just use html in a string to return, but the actual snippet would be fairly complex, and I want it to be modular.

Comment: What an incredibly unhelpful comment. Thank you.

Comment: its exactly what you are trying to do, it couldn't be more on point.

Comment: Even if it is on point, it's entirely unhelpful. You could at least *name* one of these "very many template engines" that are currently available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method is using file_get_contents and str_replace

HTML:

```
<article>
     <h1>[-HEADLINE-]</h1>
     <p>[-BODY-]</p>
</article>
```

PHP:

```
function writeArticle($headline,$body){
      $content = file_get_contents("[add your html directory here]/file.html",true);
      $content = str_replace("[-HEADLINE-]",$headline,$content);
      $content = str_replace("[-BODY-]",$body,$content);

      echo $content;
 }
```

Comment: This looks like exactly what I'd like to do. Thank you.

Comment: Welcome! Glad to help you with this problem

Answer (score 1):

You can use output buffering and include the file so the PHP variables get evaluated. However, since you are not using <?php PHP tags ?> you will need to wrap it in HEREDOC format (http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php). Scroll down to Heredoc on the page.

snippet.php

```
$output = <<<HEREDOC
<article>
  <h1>{$headline}</h1>
  <p>{$body}</p>
</article>
HEREDOC;

function writeArticle($headline, $body){
     ob_start();
     include('snippet.php');
     $snippet = ob_get_clean();
     return $snippet
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this:

```
HTML DOCUMENT
Include('blockClass.php');
$block = new blockClass();
echo $bl = $block->block($headline, $body);     

CLASS DOCUMENT
 class blockClass{

    function block($headline, $body){

      $var ='<article>
              <h1>' . $headline . '</h1>
              <p>' . $body . '</p>
             </article>';
      return $var;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same question and ended up solving it like this. I feel like this is the cleanest approach. Just turn php on and off within the function.

```
<?php
function writeArticle($headline, $body){
?>

<article>
<h1><?php echo $headline; ?></h1>
<p><?php echo $body; ?></p>
</article>

    <?php
}
?>

writeArticle('foo', 'bar');
```